# maintain postback with WebForm_DoCallback

Tags: asp.net, postback

Does anyone know how to maintain postback while calling WebForm_DoCallback? it always set the vertical scrollbar of the page to the very top.

thanks

Comment: what version of asp.net are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I Call this method in onclick event of html input button, instead of asp:Button. Sample:

```
input id="ButtonCallServer" type="button" onclick="MyServerCall(txtSum.Value)"

function MyServerCall(args) { WebForm_DoCallback('__Page', args, ClientCallbackFunction, "", null, false); }
```

Answer (score 0):

on the page you want to maintain position set the following page level directive:

```
<%@ Page Language="..." MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" ... %>
```

If you wanted you could set this for the whole site, in which case add the following to your web.config under the system.web block:

```
 <pages maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

i had similar problem yesterday after {don't remember what changes}.
the `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback` just stopped working.

use this:

```
string postbackInvokerUniqueID = Request.Forms["__EVENTTARGET"];
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(postbackInvokerUniqueID))
    Page.FindControl(postbackInvokerUniqueID).Focus();
```

that may not give the the exact scroll position, but is close enough